# AWS Route53 Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

We have one domain helloword.com on AWS Route53, we alos have one subdomain ask01.hellowword.com now we wanted to delete that subdomain (ask01.hellowword.com) and create a new subdoamin (ask02.helloword.com) and point all the links and information which was pointing to the deleted subdomain (ask01.hellowword.com)

How can do this . Please let me know step by step.

Main domain :       helloword.com

subdomain1 which i wanted to delete/remove:            ask01.helloword.com

subdomain2 which i wanted to create and point all to this:    ask02.helloword.com

Answer (score 0):

If you delete `ask01.helloword.com` then you can't forward the traffic that was going to `ask01.helloword.com` to `ask02.helloword.com`, what you can do is create the zone `ask02.helloword.com`, and create an `APEX` record in Route53 for the `ask01.helloword.com` zone that forwards `ask01.helloword.com` to `ask02.helloword.com`